# Issues with using Add-AppxProvisionedPackage to provision UWP app

Tags: windows-10, powershell, uwp

I am currently trying to manage installation a line of business UWP application on a series of client machines. I need to make sure that the application is installed for any user that signs into windows on a particular machine. To do this I am copying the APPX file of the UWP app to a provisioning directory, and using this command to provision the application:

`Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath C:\myapp-provision -SkipLicense`.

The application installs fine for users some/most of the time. However, I am running into a couple of issues fairly consistatnly.

1. Sometimes, after provisioning a new version of the application, when a new user signs into windows, they still see the previous version of the application installed.
2. Sometimes, after provisioning the application for the first time, when a new user signs into windows and searches for the app in the start menu, they get no results.

Both of these issues can be resolved by going to Apps & Features, searching for the application in list, selecting Advanced Options on the app, and then selecting reset.

This is an ok fix for the short term, but long term, I cant rely on users to always be aware that they may need to reset the app before using it.

Is there a better way I can go about getting this application installed for all users? Are there additional steps I am missing?

Comment: Have you resolved those issues? I learned that it's best to remove the provisioned package from all users which will also delete the app. then, you can add the provision again. Make sure the version of the app is different in the metadata of the app. Otherwise, it will not consider it a new version.

Comment: Note that depending on the size of the app and the order of provisioning , the app might take sometime before showing to users.

Comment: I've not tried removing the provisioned package before provisioning it. However I doubt that will work as sometimes when I provision on a new machine for the first time, it doesn't register the app for all users.

Comment: My work around for the time being, is just placing a shortcut on the desktop, that manually installs the uwp app if it's not there for this user, then launches the app. Obviously this isn't ideal and provisioning would be the best way to handle this, but I just can't get it to work the way I'd expect.

Comment: It's working fine for me to Add and Remove the provision. My only issue is that it takes a long time on the enterprise machine while in a normal machine, it will work quickly without any issues. I don't see the dependencies in your Add-AppxProvisionedPackage so this might be one reason.